# Disable designer smart tags and verbs for inherited controls

Tags: .net, winforms

I've created a `System.Windows.Forms.Control` that inherits from another control.  That other control (`System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView`, in this case, but it doesn't matter) has a [smart tag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171829.aspx) that pops up automatically when the control is dropped at design time:

[image]

This is subsequently available by clicking the small arrow circled in red above.  Also, the control has various [designer verbs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.design.designerverb.aspx) available in the context menu.

My question is: how do I disable smart tag and designer verbs so I can have more control over my, well, control?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your inherited class also inherits the `[Designer]` attribute from DataGridView.  Which is the DataGridViewDesigner class, it contains the code to add the task list and its verbs to the control at design time.  If you want to knock it out then you'll have to *replace* the designer.

Add a reference to System.Design and make your code look similar to this:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Forms;

[Designer(typeof(System.Windows.Forms.Design.ControlDesigner))]
class MyGrid : DataGridView {
    // etc..
}
```

Which is the vanilla designer for a control.  Or use System.ComponentModel.Design.ComponentDesigner if you don't like ControlDesigner either, it has no task list at all.

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing the ControlDesigner with your own:

```
[Designer(typeof(GridExDesigner))]
public class GridEx : DataGridView {

  public class GridExDesigner : ParentControlDesigner {
    private DesignerVerbCollection verbs = new DesignerVerbCollection();

    public override void Initialize(IComponent component) {
      base.Initialize(component);
    }

    public override DesignerVerbCollection Verbs {
      get {
        return base.Verbs;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Make sure to reference System.Design and the following:

```
using System.ComponentModel.Design
using System.Windows.Forms.Design
```